# Dart/Flutter: camera take low and high res picture at same time or fast convert?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-camera

I am making a camera app, that stores the pictures to my azure storage acount and lets the user interact with the pictures.

I want to have a `ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh` and a `ResolutionPreset.low` picture - the first problem is, that `ResolutionPreset.low` is for my usage a bit to hight (320x240)- maybe this could be turned manually to 133x100?

Second problem is, what I think, that the controllers output can only be one picture. For a second picture a new controller needs to be initialized.

So this is my code by now for the init-routine of the controller:

```
  late CameraController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // To display the current output from the Camera,
    // create a CameraController.
    _controller = CameraController(
      widget.camera,
      ResolutionPreset.low,
    );

   
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }
```

This is function for getting the high res picture

```
Future<XFile> image = _controller.takePicture().whenComplete(() => _controller.dispose());
```

And then I need to convert the XFile to a Uint8List to upload it to azure. - so far so good - but then the following code takes a lot of time to run, because `decodeImage`, `copyResize` and `encodeJpg` and these Uint8 conversions take a lot of time:

```
Future<String> uploadImageToAzure(Future<XFile> inputimageH) async {
    String containerH = "high";
    String containerL = "low";
    String fileName = (DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch).toString() + getRandomString(14);

    XFile imageH = await inputimageH;
    List<int> image_H = await imageH.readAsBytes();
    Uint8List pic_hight_uint8= await Uint8List.fromList(image_H);
    Image? image_H_IMG = decodeImage(pic_hight_uint8);
    Image image_L_IMG = copyResize(image_H_IMG!, height: 200,);
    List<int> image_L = encodeJpg(image_L_IMG,quality: 70);
    Uint8List pic_low_uint8=Uint8List.fromList(image_L);

    await storage.putBlob('/$containerH/$fileName.jpg',bodyBytes: pic_hight_uint8,);
    await storage.putBlob('/$containerL/$fileName.jpg',bodyBytes: pic_low_uint8,);

    return "OK";
```

The pictures that were opend by the user were stored in a global `List<Uint8List>`, so when the user closes and opens the desired case, the picture don't needs to be re-downloaded again for this app-season.

So through the way from taking a picture until displaying it and upload it I do this data-conversion:

**`XFile` > `List<int>` > `Uint8List` > `Image` > `List<int>` > `Uint8List`**

Has anybody solved this problem to make a high and a low res picture with the controller, or is there a quicker resize procedure than mine?

Worst case would be to let the high-res picture stay in the season and resize the picture with a azure function?

Thank you!

Comment: Image will always be slow, so look for something using ffi. Assuming your images are jpeg, consider https://pub.dev/packages/jpegtran_ffi

Comment: @RichardHeap - this dont work on web...